# How to define source and target when converting List<DomainObject> to List<DTO> in mapstruct?

Tags: java, mapstruct

> I am Trying to converting `List<car>` to `List<CarDto>` but not able to
>   map source and target attribute in mapstruct.  Source and target
>   mapping working fine when I convert Car to CarDto but its not working
>   with `list<car>` object

```
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {

     @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "carDetailDetail.model", target = "model")
        })
    List<CarDto> carsToCarDtos(List<Car> cars);


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is not supported in MapStruct, there is already an open feature request for it, have a look at [#1149](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1149).

However, in order to make that work you would need to define your mapping on a method between `Car` and `CarDto`, MapStruct will then use that method to perform the mapping.

Your mapper will look like:

```
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "carDetailDetail.model", target = "model")
    CarDto carToCarDto(Car car);

    List<CarDto> carsToCarDtos(List<Car> cars);       
}
```

In case you don't want to expose a public `carToCarDto` method you can use an abstract class and make the method `protected` or `package protected`.